# Javascript looping through an object

Tags: arrays, loops, object

I have an object which is given back through my REST API and I need to iterate through it for synchronizing a DB. So the object contains another object called tables. The tables object has different arrays with table names and their key value pairs. 
I could not loop through the tables object about two days whatever I did and it is really annoying getting null or undefined values back.

For example I tried iterating through the table array with the JavaScript function object.forEach((article)=>console.log(article.id,article.name));

```
const obj = response.content.tables.article;

function findArticles(obj) {
    obj.forEach((article)=>console.log(article.id,article.name));

}
```

I can't get any value back. When I try to console.log(response.content); it shows me everything. As soon as I try to output response.content.tables it says undefined.

This is the structure of the object **response.content:**

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "message": "sync out request successfull",
    "tables": {
        "article": [
          {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "baseball"
          },
          {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "truck"
          },
        ],
        "food": [],
        "animals: []
    }
}
```

Comment: Try parsing the response first. also note the missing double quote after the "animals " property. `var xyz = '{ "status": "1", "message": "sync out request successfull", "tables": {  "article": [{"id": 1,"name": "baseball"},{"id": 2,"name": "truck"}],"food": [],"animals": []}}'

console.log(JSON.parse(xyz));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
var obj = response.content;
var JSON = JSON.parse(obj);
var articleTable = JSON.tables.article;

articleTable.forEach((article)=>console.log(article.id,article.name));
```

After I parsed the response.content object to JSON it was available to access the nested objects as 'tables' and 'article'. After passing the article object with the articleTable variable to the forEach it has been possible to access each elements. Now I get results.

> I really appreciate your help 
>   T3.0 it wasn't able to solve the problem without you.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the response to an object using JSON.parse(xyz) before attempting to get the properties.

```
var xyz = '{    "status": "1",  "message": "sync out request successfull",  "tables": {     "article": [{"id": 1,"name": "baseball"},{"id": 2,"name": "truck"}],"food": [],"animals": []}}'

var obj = JSON.parse(xyz);
$(obj.tables).each(function (ix, el) {
    console.log(el)
});
```

Comment: I don't get any output. The only way I get an output with the console is var contentResponse = JSON.parse(response.content);
console.log(contentResponse). When I go deeper like response.content.tables nothing is shown. Besides I've tried to run the exact code you wrote, it doesn't log anything on the console. That's really strange.

Comment: I agree, that is strange. Run this fiddle and Check the F12 debug console. I hope it sheds some light: https://jsfiddle.net/knrd2ocq/